# Can't receive data from network using udp protocol

Tags: c++, linux, udp

My aim is to write C++ program which receives data from network using udp protocol. OS - linux. I have few questions.

1. I want to make sure that I can use linux C libraries to write C++ program.
2. Is anywhere exists full tutorial which expailns step by step how to program using sockets in linux? ( I know that in network is many tutorials, but I'm looking for something which help me receive udp data from INTERNET, not from another program on the same device.).
3. I see in terminal ( using tcpdump) that my computer receive udp packages addressed to specified port. What's wrong with my program which looks like this

   ```
   class Connection
   {
   private:
       char * buffer;
       int bufferSize;
       int sock;
       struct sockaddr_in server;
       struct sockaddr_in other;
       socklen_t addressLength;

   public:
       Connection(string address, int port, int bufferSize);
       ~Connection();
       int reciveData();
   };

   Connection::Connection(string address, int port, int bufferSize)
   {
       this->addressLength = sizeof(this->server);

       this->sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

       if(this->sock == -1)
       {
           cout << "Socket error!" << endl;
           exit(1);
       }

       memset(&(this->server), 0, sizeof(this->server));
       this->server.sin_family = AF_INET;
       this->server.sin_port = htons(port);
       this->server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

       if( bind(this->sock, (sockaddr *) &(this->server), this->addressLength) == -1 )
       {
           cout << "Bind socket error!" << endl;
           exit(1);
       }

       this->bufferSize = bufferSize;
       this->buffer = new char[bufferSize];

       cout << "Socket created!" << endl;
   }

   int Connection::receiveData()
   {
       int returned;
       fflush(stdout);

       if( (returned =recvfrom(this->sock, this->buffer, this->bufferSize, 0, (sockaddr *) &(this->other), &this->addressLength)) == -1)
       {
           cout << "Receiving error!" << endl;
           exit(1);
       }

       return returned;
   }
   ```

   When i call `receiveData()` nothing's happening - I think program waits for some udp package ( and i don't know why he does not receive it).
4. Could someone explain me difference between udp server and client program ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `recvfrom()`, you are passing it a pointer to `this->addressLength`.  On input, the length needs to be the complete size of the address buffer.  On output, the actual address length is returned.  So `recvfrom()` might be altering your `addressLength` member, affecting subsequent code.  Use a local variable instead:

```
int Connection::receiveData()
{
    int returned;
    int addrlen = sizeof(this->other);

    fflush(stdout);

    returned = recvfrom(this->sock, this->buffer, this->bufferSize, 0, (sockaddr *) &(this->other), &addrLen);
    if( returned == -1 )
    {
        cout << "Receiving error!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return returned;
}
```

Alternatively, use a separate member variable instead:

```
class Connection
{
private:
    char * buffer;
    int bufferSize;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in other;
    socklen_t serverAddressLength;
    socklen_t otherAddressLength;

public:
    Connection(string address, int port, int bufferSize);
    ~Connection();
    int reciveData();
};
```

```
Connection::Connection(string address, int port, int bufferSize)
{
    this->serverAddressLength = sizeof(this->server);

    this->sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if(this->sock == -1)
    {
        cout << "Socket error!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if(this->sock == -1)
    {
        cout << "Socket error!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&(this->server), 0, sizeof(this->server));
    this->server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    this->server.sin_port = htons(port);
    this->server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if( bind(this->sock, (sockaddr *) &(this->server), this->serverAddressLength) == -1 )
    {
        cout << "Bind socket error!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    this->bufferSize = bufferSize;
    this->buffer = new char[bufferSize];

    cout << "Socket created!" << endl;
}

int Connection::receiveData()
{
    int returned;
    fflush(stdout);

    this->otherAddressLength = sizeof(this->other);
    if( (returned =recvfrom(this->sock, this->buffer, this->bufferSize, 0, (sockaddr *) &(this->other), &this->otherAddressLength)) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Receiving error!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return returned;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, problem was with firewall.